# Having trouble sending file from server to another Client (Java)

Tags: java, file, sockets, server

I'm having some difficulties trying to send file from server to the other client.
Let's say I have two clients connected to the server.
Now Server successfully sent the file to the 1st client But then when the server tries to send to the second client the client does not receive it.
Here's some code to begin with :

Server:

```
public synchronized void sendToAllClients() {
    for (Socket z : clientSockets) {
        if (z != null) {
            System.out.println("TEST");
            PrintWriter print = null;
            try {

                File myFile = new File(FILE PATH);
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
                dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

                OutputStream os = z.getOutputStream();

                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

                dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
                dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                dos.flush();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public static void receiveFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            int bytesRead;
            InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();

            clientData = new DataInputStream(in);


            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                    (FILEPATH + FILENAME);
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0
                    && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
                            (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                size -= bytesRead;
            }

            output.flush();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to be a little more descriptive than that (what part of that code is giving you problems?). This site is not for debugging help (check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Find the problem first, then come here if you can't solve it yourself. On top of that, you're swallowing your exceptions; never do that. In your catch blocks, put `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Are you getting an error anywhere?   Are you getting the output TEST more than once?  You're reading the file completely into memory over and over, for some reason, but I don't see why it wouldn't work, barring memory issues... and a typo on the client code near new FileOutputStream (doesn't seem to have a close parens)

Comment: close your streams when the work is done.

Comment: Ok I'll edit the code and thanks for the replies